# What's the difference between writeUTF and writeChars?

Tags: java, io, objectoutputstream

What's the difference between writeUTF and writeChars? (methods of ObjectOutputStream)
Further I have not found the corresponding readChars in ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`writeUTF` writes text in UTF-8 format encoding preceeded with text length, so `readUTF` knows how many characters to read from stream.

`writeChars` writes text as a sequence of 2-bytes chars with no length. To read it, we should use `readChar` method and we need to know how many chars were written.

Comment: Eventhough there is a writeChar method in DataOutputStream, there is no readChars method in DataInputStream

Comment: ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeChars%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

**[writeChars()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeChars%28java.lang.String%29)** uses Unicode values

> Writes every character in the string s, to the output stream, in
>   order, two bytes per character. If s is null, a NullPointerException
>   is thrown. If s.length is zero, then no characters are written.
>   Otherwise, the character s[0] is written first, then s[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeChars%28java.lang.String%29), and so on;
>   the last character written is s[s.length-1]. For each character, two
>   bytes are actually written, high-order byte first, in exactly the
>   manner of the writeChar method.

**[writeUTF()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29)** uses a slightly-modified version of UTF-8

> Writes two bytes of length information to the output stream, followed
>   by the modified UTF-8 representation of every character in the string
>   s. If s is null, a NullPointerException is thrown. Each character in
>   the string s is converted to a group of one, two, or three bytes,
>   depending on the value of the character.